# How to set an action when I click outside of the popup window?

Tags: android, android-layout, popupwindow

I want to set an action or do something like change button background when click outside of the `PopupWindow`.

Here marked default button color:-
[image]

Here marked changed button color after click:-
[image]

After clicking outside of the `PopupWindow`, I want to change my button background to default.

How can i do that? I need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `OnDismissListener` for your `PopupWindow`:

```
    popupWindow.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss() {
            // Change the icon
        }
    });
```

Where `popupWindow` is the `PopupWindow` you are displaying.

Comment: That's Great. Thank you @kane O'Riley